# In Model2, should I pass HttpServletRequest from Controller to Model?

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller

In Model2, should I pass `request` to `Model` and let it handle the request to get the result I want?

```
Collection result = Model(request);
```

-or-

Should I use `x = request.getParameter("name")` in `Controller`/`Servlet` and use it to call `Model`?

```
Collection = request.getParameter("blablabla");  
Coullection result = Model(Collection);
```

Which is more like Model2? Which is more efficient?

Comment: No. Passing the request to the model violates the separation of concerns for MVC. For that reason I'd prefer the second option.

Comment: Thank you! I will try the second option now. Also thanks Andew edited the question